# Suddenly cannot browse certain website

Tags: internet

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04.

I can `ping`, `dig` and resolve any website/hostname.

But If I try to browse a particular website Google Chrome (and lynx, and firefox, and opera too) runs on timeout.

I can access the same website from Windows and Mac os, no chance to open it from Ubuntu.

Absolutely no idea. Any advice on how to debug?

PS: Already tried to change dns, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing a similar issue. This is a link to [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages). Although, its still unresolved at my end; check the updates provided and see if it solves the issue at your end.

**Edit:** The issue has been solved at my end.

Comment: strangest thing is that I'm able to PING and DIG the domain (so the dns are working the right way I guess) and I'm actually able to browse that website from another machine with Win7 or MacOS. It's sad.

Comment: As I said, we are having similar issues. I can PING and DIG the domain. And I can access that website from the **same machine** with Win7 (Dual-Boot).