# Strange networking problem. Google does not work

Tags: networking, internet, google

Google does not work, like just Google. This is the weirdest error I have ever seen.

Every 20-30 minutes Google stops working in my browser, any other page works. Then in 5-10 minutes, it just comes back.

Naturally the first thing I do is pull up the terminal and try to ping `google.com`. It works fine. Next, I try a different browser, still nothing. Next I try another computer on the same network, it loads Google no problem.

I tried both wired and wifi, I tried static ip and dynamic ip, nothing works. It seems to have a mind of its own. This is so hard to diagnose because of its intermittent nature.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google stops working in my browser"? Is this a specific Google url or all Google urls?

Comment: Anything on the google.com domain.

Comment: See if this helps: [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages). I have a PPPoE connection and faced a somewhat similar problem considering only some of the websites didn't work at my end.

Comment: what about localized domains such as google.fr or google.de?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the computer (thinking of cache issue)? Do you have the latest updates of your Ubuntu distro? What version of Ubuntu do you have (could be a bug in the networking software)? 
What network card do you have?

Comment: I second Aditya's link recommendation. Further, *are* you using some special DNS service? Are you browsing behind some national Chinese (?) firewall-filter (just checkin'..) ? Did the problem start suddenly? Any ideas as to potential triggers, such as an update or visiting a certain/new website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying a ton of things, I got frustrated and just reinstalled Ubuntu. Since then, the problem seems to have gone away.

Comment: I always have a usb with install on and a hard drive for making backups for just these sorts of occasions. Glad it's fixed for you now anyway.

Comment: I tried reinstalling too. However same problem came back some time later :S This is my question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/315955/why-i-cant-access-google-products-like-google-com-and-youtube-com

Answer (score 4):

Some (trivial, basic) ideas

- reset your router (or at least inspect its settings)
- clear browsers' cookies & cache
- reboot (*inter alia* this will clear `tmp`, can't harm)
- try in different browsers
- try with a proxy (should almost *definitely* work)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a failed but cached DNS query.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

or

```
# service dnsmasq restart
```

Then restart whatever browser you are using to wipe it's cache.

Maybe some app or plug-in you had, but forgot about, was wiped out on the re-install.