# But same web pages are opening in Windows environment

Tags: networking, internet, websites

My name is Mathew from India . Ubuntu is quite new for me . I am working in a org. where almost 300 Systems are planted . I are trying to switch to Ubuntu and installed 5 systems on Ubuntu 14.x During testing I observed some web pages are not opening .I done lot on work on it.

1. Checked with ISP for Root cause Analise.things are fine at ISP side even changed the ISP but problem is there
2. Removed all firewall things
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660821
4. [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages)
5. [Problem with internet. Certain website do not load at all. 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288040/problem-with-internet-certain-website-do-not-load-at-all-12-04)
6. Changed web Browsers
7. Loot of googling

But Problem is still there. But same web pages are opening in Windows environment.
Note :- same problem is with other flavor of linux

Comment: Check your network connection in ubuntu. Check the IPv4 settings, DNS server setting and domains value. These parameters often causes issue in accessing the internet

Comment: While it's admirable that you have included links in your question, it would be even better if you also briefly summarized the actual steps you have taken.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. To assist you better on this scenario, I would need more information about the network and web nature. How is your PC resolving DNS? when you enter the website what does it show? Finally, post a traceroute of a website which isn't working. You may try `tracepath website.com`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds silly to have to say this but you missed the most important step: working out  ***what*** the problem is. It's only going to be one of two things 99.999% of the time:

1. **DNS.** Does `host domain.ext` work? If you can't get a response, your DNS is either illegal (try a `whois domain.ext` too) or there's a network routing issue between your computer and the DNS server.
2. **Routing issues.** If you can resolve an IP from the domain but can't `ping domain.ext` (or `ping $previously-resolved-ip`), you're looking at simple networking issues. `traceroute` should indicate where things start to go wrong.

There are rare cases where other things happen (perverse proxy blocks, mysterious static routes and an attack of the plugins) but most of the time, it's either some combination of the DNS and the network.

You can usually rule Ubuntu out (or in) pretty quickly by just moving the computer to another network and trying again.