# Some websites do not load or load without css styles (longtime problem)

Tags: networking

I have a problem which i am unable to solve for about 2 years and its the reason i am not using Ubuntu as much as i would like to. I am no networking expert so some user friendly or newbie answers would be great but any help would be appreciated (i will google more info when i am pointed at right direction).
This problem persists for me for a very long time, and i was experiencing it on my notebook and second computer too. I have no problem on a different operating system. The problem is only with Ubuntu.
I cannot really say what is causing this but sometimes it just starts working and after few days its broken again (in the last half of the year it worked just once).

For example if i try to open youtube there are two possible scenarios that can occur besides that rare one which just loads the site as it should or as it is loading on different operating system. First one is that it has a very long load time and after that i get a blank page. The second more common scenario is that the page loads without css styles (just plain html code). If the page loads without css as a plain html than the video is represented by a black rectangle representing the flash plugin. Which works just fine except loading the video source.
Youtube is not that big of the deal for me. I can live without that on my ubuntu system but this problem happens with other sites too. This website or Ubuntu forums included. There are many more bugged like this. Basically like 2/3 or at least half of pages i want to load which is really frustrating and most of the time i just quit ubuntu and boot up other operating system. From the head right now i can think of imdb.com as an diferent example of this weirdness. Right now this current site loaded fast but as a plain html without any styles.
The last time it worked fine if i remember correctly was when i was using ubuntu 10.10 or something like that. Right now i am at 12.10 64bit (don't really want to update it to 13.04 for now since last updating did not ended up very good and i ended up formmating the drive).

Basically i am unable to load most of the sites i want to load or they load incorrectly,. Missing assets like stylesheets or javascript files. What i need is some help to correct this issue in some user friendly way since i dont have much experience with networking, or at least something that could guide me to the google solution.

I was searching for a solution for a very long time during that years this was bugged for me and still i am unable to resolve this. If someone can help me or at least point me at some direction that would guide me to the solution, i would be really thankful to that person. If you need to know something specific than just ask. Thanks for any help. PS: Sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE:**

Editing this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

And changing this:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Into this:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Helped untill rebooting the system (when i changed it again it worked again), at least on the sites i was beeing able to try. I am not really sure what it does or if it is wise to  edit it but for now its at least somewhat better than before. If this can bring some light to the problem and someone can find a propper solution that i would be able to follow, it would be just great. I will wait for it for a while and also to make sure it did not stop working like it did when it worked just by itself for some time. If not than i will mark it as solved and accept the answer.

**UPDATE2:**

Its a bit buggy but looks like it works. It never worked this long before. Since i edited that file i am getting "**System program problem detected**" this error. Never seen it before and it dont say anything specific (just allows me to close it). But besides that and a fact that youtube loads without thumbnail images (404 error) i did not notice anything else. Its not ideal but i can live with that. I am going to mark it as solved.

**UPDATE3:**
Some time has passed, it still works but that "**System program problem detected**" error still persists. I've created alias to change it and saved it inside

```
~/.bashrc
```

as an link to the .bash_aliases. However I don't even need to call it. It gets called automatically on the system start-up. I don't like it like that but I can live with that. Here is the alias if someone looks for that

```
alias webfix="sudo sed -i 'nameserver 127.0.1.1,nameserver 208.67.222.222d' /etc/resolv.conf"
```

Comment: There could be a range of causes. Can you answer some further questions? Does it happen in all browsers (eg - have you tried Chrome as well as Firefox). If you have Firefox installed, could you install the Firebug extension? Go to: https://getfirebug.com/ . Firebug will help get a better sense of where the problem may be arising.

Comment: Yes i have tried chrome too but there was no change so i have removed it since firefox is my favorite browser. About the firebug test ive inspected the source and it was linking to some external site on this domain http://s.ytimg.com but i was unable to load it. It throwed at me 404 error (not found). When i logged into diferent OS than the file was loaded without problem also youtube loaded correctly.

Comment: Do thins happen in a shinny new user? Create a new user and tell us if this happens. Also, are you behind a firewall/proxy? Or have you configured the iptables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages)

Comment: So ive tried to create new user (quest session, standard and admin user) and no change. About the firewall or proxy, i dont think so but i am not sure. How can i check it to be sure? I have installed some kind of firewall but it was turned off, about the proxy i did not do anything with it so i probably dont use it either. About the ip tables no i dont think i did anything to it. It had default settings. If i did change something when i was following some fix for this issue i certainly set it back to original settings after checking it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Did you try any of the methods in the link Elliah provided?

Comment: @ Braiam: Yes i did, its a bit hard for me to understand but editing resolv.conf and adding nameserver 208.67.222.222 helped (at least for all the sites i tryed). Of course it was broken uppon rebooting the system since that file is regenerated. In the comments to the answer by fred2 i posted about it. I will update the main question so its more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the solution to this problem: [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages)

It looks like it might be the same.

Comment: I think i readed that thread in the past but i am not sure since i was on many sites/topics that was suggesting something that could help any nothing really helped. I will try something with it tomorrow but i am a bit worried that it could be a bit too complicated for me. As i said before this networking stuff is not really in my comfort zone.

Comment: I would concentrate on the answer by 'laurent' as that one is very detailed. You will have to use some command line stuff in a terminal, but it does not look too complicated.

Comment: I am more concerned about the fact that i could break something and ended up without internet connection at all. Is there some way i could export and later inport that settings just in case as a safety check?

Comment: Ive carefully readed it all once again. It feels like an "alien" language to me since i dont understand many of that short terms and trying to understand it in a foreign language does not help much.Ive tried few things from there for example that sudo pppoeconf which throwed some kind of error at me that it did not respond and the reason is probably that its controlled by another process. However editing that auto generated config file and adding nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220 helped. I was beeing able to load youtube and imdb. Hope it does not break like for that dude.

Comment: Sounds like you have made progress ... good luck!

Comment: Yep i am really glad about it. :) Ive launched ubuntu now and tried to open youtube and imdb and both opened just fine. Ive also checked that file i was editing before and it was as expected in that default local ip. I hope its not just that short time fix that it worked without any change like before.

Comment: I will but i am going to wait a bit to make sure that it did not break in a few days. I dont want to mark it as solved if i am not sure if it really is.

Comment: Its a bit buggy but looks like it works. It never worked this long before. Since i edited that file i am getting "System program problem detected" this error. Never seen it before and it dont say anything specific (just allows me to close it). But besides that and a fact that youtube loads without thumbnail images (404 error) i did not notice anything else. Its not ideal but i can live with that. I am going to mark it as solved.