# Problem connecting to some websites

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, internet

I've some problem connecting to certain websites, using Ubuntu 12.04 in Dual Boot Windows 7.

Websites like https://github.com/, https://developer.paypal.com/ and https://www.facebook.com/ keeps on loading for long time.

Its so weird, it opens sometimes, then it doesn't sometimes.

I don't know how to debug this issue. So far what i tried is using PING command.

```
$ ping github.com

PING github.com (192.30.252.129) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- github.com ping statistics ---
92 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 90999ms
```

On doing that on google, it works fine.

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.236.73) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s05-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.73): icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=26.1   ms
64 bytes from maa03s05-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.73): icmp_req=2 ttl=56 time=27.7 ms
64 bytes from maa03s05-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.73): icmp_req=3 ttl=56 time=26.0 ms
64 bytes from maa03s05-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.236.73): icmp_req=4 ttl=56 time=26.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.070/26.259/27.798/0.882 ms
```

Really need some help!! I tried googling, not even sure how to search it!!

(using wireless)

Comment: Not all web servers respond to ping requests all the time. To find out if this is a browser issue or a network issue, try retrieving the sites using the `wget` command. If the page loads fast in wget, it is probably a browser issue.

Comment: @Jos: Thx! I'll check it right way!

Comment: Even your country matters.some countries like china do not allow encrypted connections.You will need to check that in your case.

Comment: github.com successfully responds to pings for me.  Also, @AdityaPatil whether or not a server responds to pings is unrelated to whether the connection is encrypted - a ping is a different type of communication that is never encrypted.

Comment: github.com successfully responds to pings for me, too. I think that It problem is related to your routers or firewalls(to github).
And china firewall allow github.com as I checked.

Comment: @neon_overload of course ping is un related to encryption, I jsut mentioned that some countries may block https sites(some of them) and some sites do not respond to pings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages)

Answer (score 0):

**Ruling out it being an HTTPS specific problem**

> Websites like https://github.com/, https://developer.paypal.com/ and https://www.facebook.com/ keeps on loading for long time.

It just so happens that these three sites all communicate over HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Some networks may block HTTPS connections, or connections on particular ports (HTTPS uses port 443 instead of port 80) as a matter of policy. However, I'm willing to guess that this isn't actually your problem. To rule out this possibility, you'll need to find an HTTPS site that works.  Does, for example, https://askubuntu.com/ work? It should.  If not, your problem may be related to HTTPS sites.

**Another type of filtering by your ISP?**

However, there is still another issue: your ping result suggests the problem is not related to your use of HTTPS (as ping does not use HTTPS).

```
--- github.com ping statistics ---
92 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 90999ms
```

This suggests that the problem isn't HTTPS. It could still be that your internet connection is filtered in some way. For example, ping could have been filtered in addition to those HTTPS connections.

**Does your internet access require a proxy?**

On the other computers that work, check if they access the web via some proxy server. This may need to be configured in your operating system. On Windows based browsers these settings can be accessed from within the browser settings of any browser - look for proxy settings.  It's possible that you need to set up equivalent proxy settings in Ubuntu.

**Could it be a routing issue with your ISP**

Occasionally an ISP may have a routing issue, whereby a connection upstream to them is temporary down, blocking access to some sites.  This will often be a temporary issue and resolved relatively quickly.

It is rare, however, for such issues to block only *some* sites but leave access to *all other* sites.  It could however mean that you can access *local* sites - sites hosted geographically near you - and are temporarily unable to access more distant sites such as overseas hosted sites.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work or not . But I think you can check the website with

[http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/](http://www.webproxy.net/)

If the website is working then install add-on to your browser form http://www.webproxy.net/

Try to visit the website. Actually it worked for me several times. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was going to say it may be a DNS problem, but after looking at your screen-shot of the ping to github.com, I don't think it is. The IP is correct, and it should reply back. I tested on my machine (12.04) here in the central U.S. and I get a average time of 68 ms and no packet loss.

You should contact your ISP and have them test your connection because something isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered what I believe is the answer to my problem.  I looked at my proxy settings and discovered that some how instead of no proxys, the setting had changed to automatically use proxy.  I accessed this by using the Firefox settings and sure enough after I restarted Firefox, all of my previously blocked websites are now accessible.  My suspicions as to how the proxy settings were changed include several firewall programs which I installed via apt-get.

Dave